# Can't connect samba domain to RSAT GPM

Tags: group-policy, samba, samba4

I have created a domain using Samba4 and while RSAT DNS works perfectly with the domain, GPM says " The Specified Domain Either Does Not Exist or Could Not Be Contacted". How can i fix this?

nslookup returns

```
Server: UnKnown
Address: 192.168.0.100

Name: nexello.lan
Address: 192.168.0.100
```

The computer with RSAT has joined the domain and RSAT DNS can edit the domain DNS, so the domain is working as far as I can see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, the domain really could not be contacted. Restarting the DC fixed the issue, who could've guessed?